# How to implement fire-and-forget messaging from one process to another?

Tags: udp, ipc, messaging, fire-and-forget

At the click of a button a simple message is to be sent from one process to another, and the message would be just a simple command with string arguments, totaling something like 50 characters (definitely much less than 1k), like

```
DisplaySomeInfo("param1", "param2")
```

and satisfying the following:

- must be **simple** (i.e. no full-blown messaging system)
- must **run on Windows**, should run on Unix
- the picture below shows my actual requirements, but it **should work with any major programming language / runtime**
- **performance is not crucial**, the whole send/receive cycle should not take more than a millisecond though for such a simple message
- **"guaranteed delivery" etc. NOT necessary**
- **sender does not care if a/the receiver got the message** - or if there is a receiver in the first place
- **no encryption/authentication/authorization necessary**

In wikipedia there is a long [list of ways to do IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Approaches), but the simplest one seems to be the non-connected socket option.

Are there any better ways (easier to implement/maintain/debug, more future proof, ...) to implement it than simply sending / receiving UDP packets (one message per packet, TTL=0), say coupled with a JSON (de)serializer?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at 0mq http://zeromq.org/

Answer (score 0):

For these requirements, simply **sending UDP unicast packets to some port on localhost** seems ideal. The only problem is that a port number has to be chosen and fixed. But if that is not an issue, simply sending and receiving UDP packets is as easy as it gets, without the need for third party libraries.

Bare-bones example for sending a UDP packet from a .Net app:

```
public static void SendUdpPacket(int destinationPort, string payload)
{
    IPEndPoint endPoint =
      new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), destinationPort);
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
    Socket socket =
      new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    socket.SendTo(buffer, endPoint);
    socket.Close();
}
```

The only open question is how to encode multiple parameters. But for that there are gazillions of ways, built into many languages is HTTP URL encoding.